# How to mark a particular function argument as a safe format string in Clang?

Tags: c, clang, compiler-warnings, variadic-functions

I have something like this:

```
static void
my_varargs_internal (const char *prefix, const char *format, va_list args)
{
    printf ("%s: ", prefix);
    vprintf (format, args);
    /* Other more complicated stuff which is why I want this to be a separate function */
    printf ("\n");
}

void
__attribute__ ((format (printf, 1, 2)))
varargs_general (const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start (args, format);
    my_varargs_internal ("General", format, args);
    va_end (args);
}

void
__attribute__ ((format (printf, 2, 3)))
varargs_specialized (const char *prefix, const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start (args, format);
    my_varargs_internal (prefix, format, args);
    va_end (args);
}
```

Compiling using Clang with `-Wformat -Wformat-nonliteral`, I get the "Format string is not a string literal" warning on the `vprintf` line. Is there a way to mark the `format` argument as an already-checked format string, since the compiler already checked it at the invocation of `varargs_general` or `varargs_specialized`? I can't do it with the `format` attribute because that will only apply to varargs functions, not ones with a `va_list` parameter.

GCC seems to understand this situation properly and doesn't warn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to suppress the warning using:

```
static void
__attribute__ ((format (printf, 2, 0)))
my_varargs_internal (const char *prefix, const char *format, va_list args)
{
    printf ("%s: ", prefix);
    vprintf (format, args);
    /* Other more complicated stuff which is why I want this to be a separate function */
    printf ("\n");
}
```

based on [Declaring Attributes of Functions:](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html)

> For functions where the arguments are not available to be checked
>   (such as vprintf), specify the third parameter as zero.